# CSS for a class is not working in IE11 only

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am adding a class error for a p tag and the css for that class is

```
.error{
border: 1px solid #ff0000 !important;
}
```

It is working fine in all other browsers. This error class is added to the element with Jquery. The class is getting added in IE11 but the css is not comming. I can see the class and its css in developer tool(inspected the textbox). But still the border is not coming.

I dont know what is wrong!

html:-`<p class="custom-multi-select-items" id="industry-items"></p>`

jquery is written in a button click

jQuery:-

```
$('.savebtn').click(function(){
$('.custom-multi-select-items').addClass('error');
});
```

P is having a css

```
.custom-multi-select-items {
width: 100%;
margin-top: -29px;
background: white;
border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
min-height: 30px;
padding: 5px;
padding-left: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Well, now you get to reduce your code to a [minimal, complete, verified example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/). In doing that you *may* work out for yourself what's going wrong. It is not, however, to do with the class-name, or the CSS property-values, itself. What's your jQuery? What's your (relevant, *minimal*) HTML?

Comment: use `$().css()` instead?

Comment: @Daniel: I realise there's ambiguity in the statement, but I *think* the OP has defined the CSS in advance, and is adding the class-name to the/an element; not *creating* CSS with JavaScript. Using `css()` to style elements introduces much more scope for error than by toggling/adding/removing class-names.

Comment: Where is your `p` CSS styles defined? (Above or below the generic `.error` declaration? And are there any other classes defined on your `<p>` element?

Comment: try removing the browser cache.. And if you have already  defined a CSS for that element. try to remove that class by
`$('#industry-items').removeClass('classname');` before you set the new CSS class.

Comment: The css for error is in main.css file it is included in header.

Comment: If you use `p.error` as your selector does the specificity make it work?

Comment: This seems to be working in IE11 for me: http://jsfiddle.net/n6seuzLj/. Are you perhaps running in compatibility mode?

Comment: In ie developer tools select the element with "Select element" (after you added the new class).
Then click the `Computed` tab on the right of `Styles` then expand the `Border-*` properties and check if the `error` class is even in the list. but instead of using `!important` you could use `.custom-multi-select-items.error`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
$('.savebtn').click(function(){
$('#industry-items').removeClass('custom-multi-select-items');
$('#industry-items').addClass('error');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.savebtn').click(function(){
$('.custom-multi-select-items').addClass('error');
}); 
 $('.removebtn').click(function(){
$('.custom-multi-select-items').removeClass('error');
});
```

```css
.custom-multi-select-items {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
  min-height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 14px;
 }
 .error{
  border: 1px solid #f00;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="custom-multi-select-items" id="industry-items">Sample text</p>
<button class="savebtn">red</button>
<button class="removebtn">remove</button>
```

I have used the code snippet and its working finely with IE11. I think you are using old version of jQuery. Can you tell me which version of jQuery are you using. I had run snippet using jQuery jquery-1.10.2.js please try your code snippet with the latest jQuery version.

Also i have added one thing to my code that you can add or remove border using addClass and removeClass method, you can check it using my code snippet.